# Eclipse, Tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

As I understood the situation, there is a conflict between the Tomcat server from outside the Eclipse with the Tomcat server from inside the Eclipse. I attached some picture that will explain the situation and I hope I can get your help[When I start the server from outside the Eclipse, but I have access the home page for the Tomcat server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EiuF.png)

[When I want to start the Eclipse server while the Tomcat still working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdtJs.png)

[I stopped the Tomcat server from the Task manager, thus the Eclipse server start without conflict][3]

[With the Eclipse sserver, I lost the access to the Tomcat home page even it says the server tomcat working][4]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tomcat server must not start from inside the Eclipse, it should start from the cmd screen by using the files startup.dat and shutdown by using the shutdown.dat file using their path in the cmd like this:

D:\Apache-Software-Foundation\Tomcat-8.0\bin\startup.bat
D:\Apache-Software-Foundation\Tomcat-8.0\bin\shutdown.bat

As well as there is another problem, which is the server should change the folder name from (Apache Software Foundation) to (Apache-Software-Foundation). Otherwise, it will cause a problem when creating the Path for the server as well as it's better to install it on the Logical partition not in the System partition to avoid any configuration problem.